# Harmonic mean larger then elements - what is a robust alternative?

Tags: statistics, means

The formula for the harmonic mean is

```
 2/mean(1/var1, 1/var2))
```

I would not expect the absolute value of the mean (whatever mean) of two values to be larger then the absolute value of each of the values. However, for the values $-800.2756851$ and $883.1436892$ this is the case with $-17057.45$. What is going on? What would be a robust version of the harmonic mean that does not have this problem?

Comment: 2/(1/800.2756851 + 1/883.1436892) = 839.670056916 (google calculator).. Everything is positive. Where does your -17 come from?

Comment: @EthanBolker: Sorry, I misspelled.

Comment: Is there still a question here? If not, just delete it.

Comment: The harmonic mean isn't really appropriate for values with different sign; consider, for example, the mean of $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @EthanBolker: My question stands. I only misspelled while writing. Not the issue.

Comment: @ConnorHarris: I am searching for a mean that punishes absolute low values like the harmonic mean. Is there are version that is useful for negative values?

Comment: To clarify, you want a measurement of the mean that (a) overweights values with small absolute value, and (b) doesn't blow up when you apply it to distributions whose range includes $0$.

Comment: @ConnorHarris: Sounds about right. An of course meanx(300,300) should be 300.

Comment: @Make42 One simple solution would be to define some weight function $f(x)$ with a peak at $0$ and even symmetry (a Gaussian $f(x) = e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$, for some appropriate choice of $\sigma$, would do nicely) and then calculate weighted means $\sum_i (x_i f(x_i)) / \sum_i f(x_i)$. I'm not sure there's a canonical way to do this.